# Need help in proving that two norms are equivalent

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis

Given two norms
$$\|x\|_1:=\sup |x(t)|+\sup |x'(t)|$$
$$\|x\|_2:=|x(0)|+\sup |x'(t)|$$ for all $t \in [0,1]$,

they are equivalent by definitions if there are positive and finite constants $a,b$ with $a\leq b$ so that $a\|x\|_1 \leq \|x\|_2 \leq \|x\|_1$.

So I have:

$$a\|x\|_1=a \sup|x(0)+x(t)-x(0)|+a \sup |x'(t)| \leq a \sup x(0)+x(t)+x(0)+a\sup |x'(t)\leq2|x(0)|a +a\sup x(t) + a \sup |x'(t)|.$$

If I choose $a:=1/(2\sup x(t))$ then I get $\frac{|x(0)|}{\sup x(t)}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \frac{\sup|x'(t)|}{\sup x(t)}$ which could be less than $\|x\|_2$ if there weren't the $1/2$ and as long as $\sup x(t)$ were positve.

How could I correct this proof? Also I haven't yet started to do the second inequality to show the equivalence.

Comment: Are these norms on $C^1[0,1]$?

Comment: Oh yes, that's what I forgot to mention.

Comment: What's the role of $b$? It's used nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from the triangle inequality and the mean-value theorem that
$$ 
|x(s)| \le |x(0)| + |x(s)-x(0)| \le |x(0)|  + s \cdot \sup_{0 \le t \le 1} |x'(t)| \le \Vert x \Vert_2
$$
for all $s \in [0, 1]$, so that $\sup_{0 \le s \le 1} |x(s)| \le \Vert x\Vert_2$ and therefore
$$
\Vert x \Vert_1 \le 2 \Vert x \Vert_2 \, .
$$
The estimate in the other direction
$$
\Vert x \Vert_2 \le \Vert x \Vert_1 \, .
$$
follows from $|x(0)| \le \sup\limits_{0 \le t \le 1} |x(t)|$.

Comment: Thank you, only one question: Why is $|x(0)| \leq \sup |x(t)|$ for $t \in [0,1]$?

Comment: $\sup\limits_{0 \le t \le 1} |x(t)|$ is an upper bound for the set of all values $|x(t)|$, $0 \le t \le 1$. In particular it is $\ge |x(0)|$.

Comment: Ah, of couse, thank you.